# Low gpu usage of tensorflow in Windows

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, gpu

I recently installed tensorflow-gpu for Windows 10, and I followed all of the steps, including CUDA 9.0 and cudadnn. But computation speed doesn't increase dramatically after I run the code.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(777)

origin_data=np.load("train-imgs.npz")['arr_0']
answer_data=np.load("train-labels.npz")['arr_0']

d2_origin_data,answer_2d=[],[]

for i in range(len(origin_data)):
    d2_origin_data.append(origin_data[i].flatten())

answer_data=np.reshape(answer_data,(-1,1))

num_classes=10

input_feed=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,len(d2_origin_data[0])])
answer_feed=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None,1])
w=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([len(d2_origin_data[0]),num_classes]))
b=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))

with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    our_answer=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(input_feed,w*0.001)+b)
    vec_answer=tf.one_hot(answer_feed,num_classes) 
    vec_answer=tf.reshape(vec_answer,[-1,num_classes]) #reduce dimension
    cost=tf.reduce_meantf.reduce_sum(vec_answer*tf.log(our_answer),axis=1))
train=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto( allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(1000):        
    cost_val,acc,_=sess.run([cost,accuracy,train],feed_dict{input_feed:d2_origin_data,answer_feed:answer_data})
    if i%50==0:
        print(i,acc,cost_val)
```

**GPU usage:**

[image: gpu usage]

**CPU usage:**

[image: cpu usage]

I used 62.8mb 'train-imgs.npz' file and 160kb 'train-labels.npz' file. 
As shown above photes, gpu utilisation fluctuates and doesn't exceeds 90%. I think training step is still low as I run the code with GPU because of low GPU utilisation.

However, when I run the cnn code which requires more complex calculation my laptop uses GPU over 60% consistently.
I knew that GPU usage depends on networks size, batch size and preprocessing. How should I do in order to increase GPU usage over 90% consistently?

Comment: You are using `feed_dict()`, which is outdated and slow, you can increase your speed by using the `tf.dataset()` api and use it's generator functions to feed to your training graph